# How do I preserve the formatting of multiline comment when updating an XML node?

Tags: xml, powershell, comments, multiline

We have a kind of configuration file which starts with a lot of explanation in a comment part and then has the simple configuration part in the end.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!--
  # line 1
  # line 2

  # line 4
-->
<Info>
<Server>server1</Server>
</Info>
```

This is nicely formatted with blank lines etc to make it readable in Notepad/Editor.

Now when I update the Server e.g. and save the file, the formatting is all garbled.

I tried with adding `$X.preservewhitespace = $true`, but to no avail.

```bsh
[XML]$X = Get-Content c:\tmp\demo.xml
$X.Info.Server = "newservername"
$X.Save("C:\tmp\demo-out.xml")
```

Is there any option or other method to keep the formatting in the command part when saving the file?

Comment: Can't reproduce. I tested the code you posted (in PowerShell 5.1) and it left the whitespace in the comment untouched. But as an alternative you could try `$xml = New-Object Xml; $xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true; $xml.Load('c:\tmp\demo.xml')`. Also, what PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: thanks. it's PS Version 5.1.14393.206 on a Windows Server 2016. I made up above sampe as miniversion of the real Thing, but created now to be sure. using "my" Version with only get-Content into [XML]$X Fails as described. all the comment lines are collapsed into one single line. using $X.preservewhitespace = $true collapese the complete contenten into one line (using Notepad to create Initial XML demo file and looking at Output files. BUT: your recommendation with using new-Object XML works fine. so I'll try that on the big Version. thanks